# how to check if a graph exists or not in marklogic database?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

I am using java-api of Marklogic database, As per my requirement I delete the triple graph each time I receive request and then create a new one with triples. For now I have wrapped the code in try-catch block to catch exception and proceed.

```
try {
    GraphManager graphManager = client.newGraphManager();
    graphManager.setDefaultMimetype(RDFMimeTypes.NTRIPLES);
    graphManager.delete(graphUri)
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // do nothing for this
}
```

Is there any better way to check for the existing graph of triples with graph manager, I have seen graph manager class, but I didn't find any way to check availability of graph.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this endpoint:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/HEAD/v1/graphs

I prefer to use:
https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/graphs
With the named graph and category set to 'metadata.

Comment: Hey i am using graph manager of java-api for triples, is there any way to check if graph exists or not through GraphManager, i have updated the question again.

Comment: The closest is what Dave Cassel suggests - but in my case, with temporal data, listing existing graphs would, I believe,  result in millions of responses.  Using GraphManager, other than iterating over the list of available graphs, the only other option is to try to do an action on a graph and catch the ResourceNotFoundException failure(like getPermissions). But this is the approach you are already using already, I believe.

Comment: yes, catching the exception is what i am doing already, i thought there might be something to check if it exists, like rest head call you suggested, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

With GraphManager, call [`listGraphUris`](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/semantics/GraphManager.html#listGraphUris()). That will give you an `Iterator<String>`. Loop through that to check whether the URI of the graph you're interested in is present.

Comment: I did not mention this one because if you also have temporal data, the number of graphs can make this approach likely costly.

Comment: In the presence of enough collections to make `listGraphUris` a bad idea, I'd write a REST extension to do what I needed and call that through the Java API.